# Closedness of a set of measures, where conditional marginals are in closed $\varepsilon$-ball w.r.t. Wasserstein distance

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(E,d)$ be a bounded polish space (separable, complete metric space satisfying $\sup_{x,y\in E} d(x,y) < \infty$). By $\mathcal{P}(E)$ we denote the space of Borel probability measures on $E$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence.

We fix $\varepsilon > 0$, $\theta \in \mathcal{P}(E)$ and a stochastic kernel $\pi$ on $E$ (I.e. $\pi: E\times Bor(E) \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\pi(x,\cdot)$ is a Borel measure for all $x\in E$ and $\pi(\cdot,A)$ is measurable for all Borel sets $A\subseteq E$).

We assume that $\pi$ satisfies the strong Feller property, i.e. $x_n \rightarrow x\in E \Rightarrow \pi(x_n,\cdot) \stackrel{w}{\rightarrow} \pi(x,\cdot)$, where $\stackrel{w}{\rightarrow}$ denotes weak convergence.

We define
\begin{align*}
M := \{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}(E^2) &: \text{If } \mu = \mu_1 \otimes K, \text{ where } \mu_1 \in \mathcal{P}(E) \text{ and } K \\ &\text{ is a stochastic kernel on } E, \text{ then } \\ &W_1(\mu_1,\theta) \leq \varepsilon \text{ and } \\&W_1(K(x,\cdot), \pi(x,\cdot)) \leq \varepsilon \text{ for } \mu_1\text{-almost all } x\in E.\},
\end{align*}
where $W_1$ is the first Wasserstein distance on $\mathcal{P}(E)$ given by
\begin{align*} 
W_1(\nu,\mu) &= \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\nu,\mu)} \int_{E^2} d(x,y) \pi(dx,dy)\\
&= \sup_{\substack{f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\\ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq d(x,y)}} \left( \int_E f d\nu - \int_E f d\mu\right)
\end{align*}
and $\Pi(\nu,\mu)$ is the set of measures on $E^2$ with first marginal $\nu$ and second marginal $\mu$.

**Question: Is M closed?**

Remarks:

By boundedness of $(E,d)$ weak convergence is compatible with the Wasserstein distance, i.e. $\mu_n \stackrel{w}{\rightarrow} \mu \in \mathcal{P}(E) \Leftrightarrow W_1(\mu_n,\mu) \rightarrow 0$.

If $\pi$ does not satisfy the strong Feller property, $M$ is in general not closed. Take for example $\varepsilon = 0.5, E = [0,1], \theta = \delta_0, \pi(0,\cdot) = \delta_1$ and $\pi(x,\cdot) = \delta_0$ for $x \neq 0$. Then $M\ni\delta_{1/n} \otimes \delta_0 \stackrel{w}{\rightarrow} \delta_0 \otimes \delta_0 \not\in M$.

Even if $\pi$ is constant, I don't know whether $M$ is closed and would be very interested in an answer for this case as well.

Comment: Are you willing to assume those Borel measures admit finit second moments?

Comment: This is certainly an important special case and a solution would be very interesting to me. Do you have a method in mind that requires finite second moments?
And just to clarify, admitting finite second moments in the sense of restricting $M$ to measures that have finite second moments?

Comment: Yes, if you are willing to assume finite second moment, I will try to think of it and probably have a direction using duality. However, I have no idea beyond $L^2$.

Comment: Ok, as mentioned I would be very interested in this case. However, in the context I'm working in one doesn't usually require moment restrictions so the general case would still be preferable. But if it's just about accepting the answer then the $L^2$-case would be sufficient for me if nothing else turns up.

Comment: I think we can relax to finite first moment due to how I use the result. Correct the wrong solution I posted earlier.

Comment: I just realized that since we are in a bounded setting ($\sup_{x,y} d(x,y) < \infty$) all moments are finite anyway (unless I'm missing something now), so this is no restriction at alI. Actually in your proof and for the measures one would require this for $E^2$ instead of $E$...Not completely sure about this at the moment but I will think about it and study your proof closely tomorrow as soon as I have time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $\pi,K$ are conditional marginals, they cannot have infinite moments if the joint measures have finite moments(think of the iterative moment formula for conditionals), so it suffices to assume on $E$. But if I understood it wrongly and they are just sto. kers, then yes, you need to assume it for $E^2$ for the whole argument. If I may ask, can you also let me know the motivation of this problem?

Comment: About the motivation: It arose by studying a type of Large Deviations result for Markov Chains, in a certain "robust" way, which allows for small perturbations of initial distribution and transition kernel with respect to the Wasserstein distance.

Comment: Why not try to write it in spectral representation and perturb on the spetrum?